# How to wait for keyboard input before clearing screen (getchar not working)

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to write a program, where in I'm displaying something before clearing the screen and moving onto the next screen.  I'm using system("clear") to clear the screen.  But I'm noticing that it just clears the screen way too fast.  What I mean is, even though, I've put a getchar() , it just does not wait for the keyboard input and executes the next command.  I'm unable to figure out why !

Here's my code for the pause macro which is supposed to wait for a keystroke:

```
#define pause() \
do{ \
    cout<<"Press any key to continue";\
    getchar();\
} while(0);
```

And here's the code which uses the above macro, but the below code doesn't wait for key to be pressed before clearing the screen !

```
void registerUser()
{
    string uid,passwd;
    cout <<"Enter UID: ";
    cin >> uid;
    cout<<" Enter Password: ";
    cin>>passwd;
    bool ret = addUser(uid,passwd);
    if (ret == false)
    {
        cout<<"User "<< uid <<" already exists\n"; // This message is not displayed
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"User " << uid <<" Successfully added\n"; // This message is not displayed
    }
    pause();  // Program does not wait here as expected
    system("clear");  // Screen is cleared immediately !!
}
```

Comment: why don't use inline? Macros are not a good tool for this

Answer (score 3):

`std::cin` reads characters from the input stream (typically `stdin`). It stops when it reads a delimiter, the default delimiter is `\n`.

So when it reads a sequence, **there is a trailing newline still in the stream**!

`getchar()` will then read that `\n`, and return. That's why there is no pause. You'll have to remove the newline from the stream:

```
std::cin.ignore(); //Discards 1 character from the stream
```

Answer (score 2):

`getchar` "will work", the problem is that in your case, you are reading the newline left behind by `cin >> passwd;`.

The appropriate way to resolve this is `cin.ignore(1000, EOF);` which will ignore all characters up to and including the next newline.

Or don't clear the screen, it's very nice to be able to scroll back and see what you've been doing in the past, and clearing the screen destroys that.